# Define a Laravel route with a variable part that is not a parameter?

Tags: url, laravel, routes

I want to define a route like this:

```
Route::put('businesses/?!?/reviews/{review_id}', 'BusinessesController@editReview');
```

that match urls like:

```
businesses/-1/reviews/12or

business/abc/review/12
```

but calls the `BusinessController::editReview` method with only the `review_id` argument:

```
function edit_review($review_id) { ... }
```

Effectively making the  `?!?` part mandatory but ignoring its value.

EDIT: the point is the editReview method should have exactly one argument. Besides, I want to give the route a name and call it with exactly one argument:

```
route('business.review',['review_id'=>1])
```

EDIT: Now that I think about it, what is supposed to go in '?!?' part with the above `route(...)` call ?

Comment: Why not just add a method argument but not use it? `function edit_review($ignore_this, $preview_id){}`

Comment: well that's the whole point :-) I want it to have exactly 1 argument for some reasons that can not be eliminated. Besides, I want to give it a name and call it with exactly one argument : `route('business.review',['review_id'=>1])`.

Comment: I see you already figured out my next question. What should actually go in `?!?`? Maybe it helps if you explain what you actually want to do...

Answer (score 0):

This is typically solved using a nested controller (see the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#implicit-controllers), you need to scoll down a little bit)

**Controller**

```
class BusinessReviewController extends BaseController {

    public function show($businessId, $reviewId)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

**Route**

```
Route::resource('businesses.reviews', 'BusinessReviewController');
```

This enables you to call the routes like you want to (`businesses/1/reviews/12` or `route('business.review',['businessId' => 1, 'reviewId' => 12])`)

Basically, this is a ResourceController as usual, having all the routes a normal ResourceController has. just run `php artisan routes` to see what you got (since your example was about edit, but mine should get you started...).